# Need to replace a value in SYS.XMLTYPE in Oracle

Tags: xml, oracle

Am trying to replace a string in oracle of data type SYS.XMLTYPE, I tried using below query, but it looks like this can be only used for dataType VARCHAR2.

```
update RECORD_TABLE set MB_RECORDS=replace(MB_RECORDS, '<Currency/>', '<Currency></Currency>') where MB_RECORD_ID ='23667';
```

How can we do this, when the data type for MB_RECORDS is SYS.XMLTYPE ?

Strangely, this works for select statement on same column.

```
select replace(MB_RECORDS, '<Currency/>', '<Currency></Currency>') from RECORD_TABLE where MB_RECORD_ID ='23667';
```

Answer (score 0):

in a select statement there is an implicit conversion to VARCHAR2, replace returns VARCHAR2 as well.

in update statement your replace returns VARCHAR2, just like in SELECT, but your expected type is XMLTYPE

```
Decalre
REF_DOC XMLTYPE;
Begin
 REF_DOC := SYS.XMLTYPE.CREATEXML(InputString);
-- and then insert or update
End;
```

Why do you need to replace

```
<tag> with <tag></tag>?
```

Point is that there are functions to manipulate XMLTYPE in ORACLE, but you are replacing butter with butter, so I am not sure that they will understand what you are trying to do.

Here is [the document how to work with XMLTYPE](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B10500_01/appdev.920/a96620/xdb04cre.htm), search for Example 4-32.

Comment: For some reason, I am unable to insert the values for Currency tag, So I just wanted to replace that with <tag></tag>. The above method will store the current value in 'REF_DOC' variable, I have to edit and the I have to insert or update. But, how to edit that variable ?. Thanks for your help

Comment: Thanks again for you update, problem is Example 4-32 illustrates how to update the value in between the tags, I want to change the tag itself, Reason is, this kind of a template which I use it in my next code to populate the variables.

Comment: Again you can't change <tag/> to <tag></tag>. They are the same thing. any xml parser/builder can freely choose how to represent it, but there is a tendency for the shorter version. So, unless you want this currency to have some value, you can't change how tags are presented. You could delete or create a tag, but again how it is presented would be determined by xml processor.